# Downloading a slack file just returns login page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I'm trying to download a file from slack, using Node. I'm think what I've got should work in theory - but I just seem to keep getting the login page as a response and I can't work out why. I've also tested via postman too and get the same result.

[image]

I believe I've followed the correct steps according to https://api.slack.com/tutorials/working-with-files with the bearer token. I'm using my own token trying to download an image that I posted - so I should have permission to do so. I've used this same token with the `node-sdk` without any problems.

```
// file.url_private = https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TDGL0NYUE-FHQN2HRQQ/download/brian.jpg
// token = xoxp-4586..........

const options = {
    url: file.url_private,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.token}`,
    }
};
        request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`c:/temp/test/${file.title}`));
```

The pipe etc is working correctly, but saving a login html page instead. I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So having set up my scopes a while ago, I forgot about them. Turns out the scope of the token I created didn't have the `files.read` permission required to download a file!